# WPF vs XNA for Imagerendering for Surface 2.0

Tags: wpf, image, xna, pixelsense

I'm creating an image viewer for MS Surface 2.0.

I'm having big performance troubles since the images are huge (read: 3840x3840) while using WPF, but I think it's because of the WPF Image rendering.

I was wondering, if you need to render a lot of big images, is it better to render with XNA or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the XNA HiDef profile on your hardware, you can have textures up to 4096-square in size ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx)), before you have to chop them up into separate textures.

I'm afraid I'm not sure what WPF performance is like. Although I expect that if you are using hardware rendering correctly (and not somehow hitting a software-rendering path) it would not be massively dissimilar to to XNA.

I think your best bet is to create some test apps that render textures of similar number and sizes to your final app, and measure what the performance is like for each API.